# custom styling in vaadin web component from angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, vaadin

I am trying to add a Vaadin web component to an Angular app.
I went through the docs on importing a Vaadin web component to an Angular application:
https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/using-web-components-in-angular

After cofiguring everything and installing the necessary component from npm (vaadin-date-picker), I created an instance from the component. I can see it in the application. The problem is with the custom styling. I read that I need to create a dom-module and create a theme but the component stays as is without the changes from the theme.
I took these lines from their official docs and it doesn't work for me:

```
<dom-module id="custom-input-field-style" theme-for="vaadin-text-field">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host([theme~="custom-input-field-style"]) [part="input-field"] {
        background-color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<vaadin-date-picker theme="custom-input-field-style" label="Label"></vaadin-date-picker>
```

I noticed that this example is not even working in their official docs. Maybe this is a problem with the package itself?
Thanks!

Comment: Your `theme-for` should be set to the element(s) you want to have that custom style, even though your style rule might affect a text field, the `:host` in your styles still refer to the date picker, so it should have `theme-for="vaadin-date-picker"`.

Comment: No change. It doesn't work... I think that this is something in the package itself. 
 @ErikLumme

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue by applying custom styles for `vaadin-checkbox` component, this was my solution:

1.- You need to install Origami: `npm install @codebakery/origami` which is a set of utilities in order to connect Angular + Polymer. Follow the installation steps provided by them: https://github.com/hotforfeature/origami

2.- Copy the styling code inside `<head>` tag of index.html:

```
<head>
  ....

  <dom-module id="checkbox-button-icon-color" theme-for="vaadin-checkbox">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host([theme~="custom"][checked]) [part="checkbox"] {
          background-color: #F5DEB3;
        }
      </style>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

</head>
```

3.- Do the following inside your app.component.ts. You have to include the styles for the root component (so the change applies for all the child components), don't forget to use the id of the dom-module you wish to implement

```
...
import { IncludeStyles } from '@codebakery/origami/styles';

@IncludeStyles('checkbox-button-icon-color')
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   ...
```

4.- An finally use the theme on the actual component across the app:

```
<vaadin-checkbox checked theme="custom" value="1">...</vaadin-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom styles can be added by function [`registerStyles()`](https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/blob/master/packages/vaadin-themable-mixin/vaadin-themable-mixin.js#L36) within an Angular component.

It is important that `registerStyles()` is executed prior the web component is created. Vaadin's web components are created automatically when the component is imported.

It is sufficient if `registerStylesPriorWebComponent()` is executed once.

```
import { registerStyles, css } from '@vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin/register-styles.js'

let executedOnce = false

export class MultiSelectComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.registerStylesPriorWebComponent()
    }

    registerStylesPriorWebComponent() {
        if (executedOnce) { return }

        registerStyles(
            'vaadin-multi-select-combo-box',
            css`
                [part='label'] {
                    color: red !important;
               }
            `
        )
        import('@vaadin/multi-select-combo-box')

        executedOnce = true
    }
}
```